# Cannot capture the packet using libpcap

Tags: c, system-calls, ethernet, libpcap, raw-sockets

I am kind of new to use libpcap.

I am using this library to capture the packet and the code i wrote to the capture the packet is below.

The interface that I am tapping is always flooded with arp packet so there is always packet coming to the interface.But I cannot able to tap these packet. The interface is UP and running. 
I got no error on pcap_open_live function.

The code is in C. And I am running this code on FreeBSD10 machine 32 bit.

```
void captutre_packet(char* ifname , int snaplen) {

    char ebuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    int pflag = 0;/*promiscuous mode*/
    snaplen  = 100;
    pcap_t* pcap =  pcap_open_live(ifname, snaplen, !pflag , 0, ebuf);
    if(pcap!=NULL) {
            printf("pcap_open_live for %s  \n" ,ifname );   
    }

    int fd = pcap_get_selectable_fd(pcap);
    pcap_setnonblock(pcap, 1, ebuf);

    fd_set fds;
    struct timeval tv;

    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(fd, &fds);

    tv.tv_sec = 3;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    int retval = select(fd + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

    if (retval == -1)
            perror("select()");
        else if (retval) {
            printf("Data is available now.\n");
            printf("calling pcap_dispatch \n");
            pcap_dispatch(pcap , -1 , (pcap_handler) callback , NULL);
        }
        else
            printf("No data within 3 seconds.\n");
 }  
    void
    callback(const char *unused, struct pcap_pkthdr *h, uint8_t *packet)
    {
            printf("got some packet \n");
    }
```

I am always getting retval as 0 which is timeout.
I don't know what is happening under the hood I follow the tutorial and they also did exactly the same thing I do not know what i am missing.

**I also want to understand how the packet from the ethernet layer once received get copied into this opened bpf socket/device (using pcap_open_live) and how the buffer is copied from kernel space to user space?**

**And for how long we can tap the packet till the kernel consume or reject the packet?**

Comment: _"Cannot able to tap the packet..."_ `o.O` what do you exactly mean by *"tap the packet"* ?

Comment: @JoeyMallone I mean Capture by tap.

Answer (score 0):

The `pcap_open_live()` call provided 0 as the packet buffer timeout value (the fourth argument).  libpcap does not specify what a value of 0 means, because different packet capture mechanisms, on different operating systems, treat that value differently.

On systems using BPF, such as the BSDs and macOS, it means "wait until the packet buffer is completely full before providing the packets.  If the packet buffer is large (it defaults to about 256K, on FreeBSD), and the packets are small (60 bytes for ARP packets), it may take a significant amount of time for the buffer to fill - longer than the timeout you're handing to `select()`.

It's probably best to have a timeout value of between 100 milliseconds and 1 second, so pass an argument of somewhere between 100 and 1000, not 0.